# jQuery Autosize plugin on dynamically added textarea elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, textarea, autosize

Hi :) I'm using [jQuery Autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) plugin to resize some of my textarea elements dynamically. Everything is good but the problem is that when I add some textarea elements to the DOM dynamically, the autosize thing no longer works.

I initialize the plugin like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('textarea').autosize();
    });
```

I tried to enable the plugin for my dynamically added textareas like:

```
myDynamicallyAddedTextarea.autosize();
```

Unfortunately, nothing happened. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: did you get this to work? Dynamically varying height.

Answer (score 3):

sorry I can't comment yet, where are you adding this textarea at? can you post some of the code around the dynamic generation so that I can see when this stuff is getting called?

according to [the docs](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/autosize), all you have to do is something like this for dynamically added elements...

```
function addTextArea() {
  $(body).append($('<textarea class="test" />'));
  $('.test').autosize();
});

//somewhere in code, but must be after the autosize plugin js has loaded
addTextArea();
```