# Use same functions for new DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site I use jQuery autosize library.

It is used on textareas, and are defined in my javascript.js file, with just:

```
$(".autosize").autosize();
```

The problem is that when I want to load new textareas into my site using ajax, I need to write this again in the ajax return. Fx:

```
<textarea name='something' class='autosize'></textarea>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(".autosize").autosize();
</script>
```

Is it not possible for the new textareas inserted into the DOM, to automatically "act" according to the javascript.js file from my header?

FYI, this questions is simplified a lot and the real case is on a much larger scale.

Comment: check this lick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410696/jquery-autosize-plugin-on-dynamically-added-textarea-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using ajax to add the item then in the global js file you may do something like below.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
   $(".autosize").autosize();
});
```

Using deprecated DOMNodeInserted listener

```
 $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.autosize', function(e) {
       $(".autosize").autosize();
    });
```

Comment: [_This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) Always consider browser support. It may work in your browser but may not work with others..

Comment: @RayonDabre Is there another method that has replaced this method?

Comment: `AJAX` global handler ? Initialize it every time `success` is invoked..But I would initialize it manually every time I insert new target element which has to be attached to any widget...